# FTP required username and password in opencart on localhost (windows)

Tags: php, ftp, frameworks, localhost, opencart

In Opencart I am trying to install Ocmod module. but its need to enable FTP from my opencart admin panel. When i am trying to enable my FTP. It needs to config Username and password for my localhost. My username is root. but I don't have any password of my root. but password field is required.

So my main question is what is the password of my localhost. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Replace your 'empty' password with a password in your configuration so you have a password on your localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right way to install extension folder on localhost.

In XAMP run FileZilla.

Click on Admin button in xampp.

If you have password then fill it otherwise click 'ok'

Now in Edit > user Create a new user here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install extension on localhost that is created by OCMOD. please use following steps:

1. Extract the extension
2. Copy all files of the upload directory and paste in root directory of opencart.
3. Rename the .xml file to .ocmod.xml
4. Now install .ocmod.xml file using opencart installer.
5. Your extension will be install successfully.

Enjoy :)